# One assumption in the proof of one result of Hahn-Banach theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

**Theorem**: Let $X$ be a locally convex space, let $M$ be a linear subspace of $X$, and let $f\in M^*$. Then there exists $h\in X^*$ such that $h(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in M$.

I saw one sentence in the proof that I don't understand. It is:

Replacing $M$ by $\overline{M}$ and replacing $f$ by its unique continuous linear extension to $\overline{M}$, we can assume that $M$ is closed in $X$.

My question is what is the reason to replace $M$ and $f$ and why we can assume that $M$ is closed in $X$?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's handle the technical problem (why can we assume $M$ is closed and $f$ is continuous on $M$?)  Recall that the topology on any locally convex space is generated by some family of seminorms $p_\alpha$.  Thus, a function $f$ is continuous on $M$ if and only if
$$|f(x-y)| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n c_i p_{\alpha_i}(x-y)$$
for soem finite $n$ and $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$.  Now, let $x \in \overline{M}$ and $(x_\kappa)_\kappa$ a Cauchy net in $M$ converging to $x$.  Then, $f(x_\kappa)$ is a Cauchy net in $\mathbb{R}$, so it converges to some limit, call it $f(x)$.

Now, to see that this extension of $f$ is continuous, let $(x_\mu)_\mu$ be another Cauchy net converging to $x$.  Then,
$$\begin{align*}|f(x-x_\mu)| &\leq |f(x) - f(x_\kappa)| + |f(x_\kappa - x_\mu)|\\
& \leq |f(x) - f(x_\kappa)| + \sum_{i=1}^n c_i p_{\alpha_i}(x_\kappa - x_\mu)\\
&\leq |f(x) - f(x_\kappa)| + \sum_{i=1}^n c_i p_{\alpha_i}(x - x_\kappa) + \sum_{i=1}^n c_i p_{\alpha_i}(x - x_\mu)\end{align*}$$
The first term on the right can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $\kappa$ appropriately by the definition of $f(x)$.  Likewise, the second and third terms can be made small in the limit (of nets) since $(x_\kappa)_\kappa$ and $(x_\mu)_\mu$ are both Cauchy nets converging to $x$.

As to why we want to do this, it helps to remember the proof strategy: we want to argue that if $M$ is a strict subspace of $X$ with a continuous linear functional $f$ defined on it, then there always exists a superspace $N \supsetneq M$ and a continuous functional $g$ with $g|_{M} = f$ (Zorn's lemma then tells us that $h$ exists).  We construct $N$ as a codimension $1$ extension of $M$: that is, we choose some $x \not\in M$, define $N = M + \operatorname{span}(x)$, and define $f(x)$ somehow and extend by linearity.

If $M$ is closed, then we are free to choose $f(x)$ however we like (and various refined versions of the theorem choose $f(x)$ so that the global extension $h$ has some nice geometric/analytic properties).  If $M$ is open, however, we are not be able to choose $f(x)$ freely if $x \in \partial M$, so we would have to define $f(x)$ by continuity anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you be more specific on why we can assume $M$ is closed?

Comment: Because if $M$ is not closed, we can extend $f$ to the closure of $M$ by uniform continuity.

Comment: I am sorry that I am a little slow. Let's say M is not closed. Then how to extend $f$? Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the proof that a uniformly continuous function on an open interval can be continuously extended to the endpoints of the interval?

Comment: Yes. I think I know what you mean. If M is not closed, then we can extend $f$ to $\overline{M}$. So we can say $M$ is closed.

Comment: I think about this question again. But in this case it is a locally convex space there is no open intervals. Are there any results in locally convex spaces.

Comment: The result you want goes "A uniformly continuous function defined on a dense subset of a metric space can be (uniquely) continuously extended to the whole space."  The proof is the same as the usual real analysis proof for extending from the open interval to the endpoints.  I encourage you to try to find the proof on your own, and if you get stuck, to ask another question.

Comment: Can this result use in a locally convex space?

Comment: @AnswerLee See my edit

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is really helpful. But there are two things that I didn't follow. What does the extension look like and why the extension is continuous by show the Cauchy net convergence?

Comment: I am really sorry to bother you. I think I understand your proof now. But only one thing I still feel a little confused is how to show the extension of $f$ in linear? Thanks!

Comment: Certainly, $f(ax_\lambda + by_\mu) = af(x_\lambda) + bf(y_\mu)$ for $x_\lambda, y_\mu$ nets in $M$.  Now, if $x_\lambda \to x$ and $y_\mu \to y$, what happens if we take limits (in $\lambda$ and $\mu$)?

Comment: Thanks for your patience! But I am stuck on how to get $\lim f(x_\lambda+y_\mu)=\lim f(x_\lambda)+\lim f(y_\mu)$? And how is $x_\lambda+y_\mu$ defined by the way?

Comment: Take the limit in each index ($\lambda$ and $\mu$) separately.  $x_\lambda + y_\mu$ is the just the sum of two vectors.

Comment: I think the extension $g$ of $f$ is defined by $g(x)=\lim\limits_{i}x_i$ ($x\in\overline{M}$). But I don't think it is well defined, since for $x\in\overline{M}$, there may exist $x_i\to x$ and $y_k\to x$. And how to make sure $\lim\limits_{i}x_i=\lim\limits_{k}y_k$?